# jquery slidedown and slideup wiggles div

Tags: jquery, html, css, razor, toggle

http://eusville.com/eusVote/1/baltimore-sushi

Click "Add Comment/Rate" button. As the comment box slides down, the page wiggles. Am very stumped. Googled around but can't find solution.

Odd thing is problem is in Chrome and Firefox. IE works smooth ...

The HTML div is:   ... sorry, there's a lot of razor stuff there. Just ignore the @s ...

jQuery slides this Div up and down.

Tips appreciated !  TIA.

```js
$(".buttonAddCommentRate").click(function () {    
    var crBox = $(this).closest('.answer-container').find('.answer-commentRateBox');    
    var buttonText = $(this).text();

    if (buttonText == 'Add comment/rate') {
        crBox.slideDown(300);
        $(this).text('Cancel comment/rate');
    }
    else {
        crBox.slideUp(300);
        $(this).text('Add comment/rate');
    }
});
```

```css
.answer-comment{
    width:600px;
         float: left;
}
.answer-textArea{
    width: 500px;
    height: 180px;     
}

.answer-commentRateBox{
   display:none;
   overflow: hidden;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="answer-container">
            <div class="answer-main">
                <h4>@Model.ElementAt(i).Title</h4>

                @Model.ElementAt(i).Detail<br /><br />

                <button class="buttonAddCommentRate" data-id="@Model.ElementAt(i).AnswerID">Add comment/rate</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <span class="span-buttonAddCommentRate">Log in to comment and/or rate</span>
            </div>

            <div class="answer-eusScore">
                eusScore (<span class="answer-count">@Model.ElementAt(i).Count</span>)<br /><br />
                <span class="span-answer-eusScore">@(Math.Round((decimal)(Model.ElementAt(i).RatingScore)))%</span>
            </div>
            <div class="answer-thankYou">
                Rating/comment posted
            </div>

            <br style="clear:both" />

            <div class="answer-commentRateBox">
                <br />
                <div class="answer-comment">
                    <textarea class="answer-textArea" placeholder="Comment must be more than 5 words ..."></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="answer-rateIt">
                    <input data-id="@Model.ElementAt(i).AnswerID" type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=0.5 data-size="sm"><br />
                    <br /><br />
                    <button class="buttonSubmit" disabled data-id="@Model.ElementAt(i).AnswerID">Submit</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="buttonCancel">Cancel</button><br />
                    <span id="span-enable-message" style="font-size:smaller">(rate to enable)</span>
                </div>
                <br style="clear:both" />
            </div>

            <div>
                @*displays the comments using a partial view*@
                @{Html.RenderAction("Comments", "Topic", new { answerID = @Model.ElementAt(i).AnswerID });}
            </div>

        </div>

        <hr />
```

Comment: make the body `overflow:hidden` on slidedown & change to `overflow:auto` after it slides up

Comment: thanks amit, will try when I get home tonight. one thing I note at work. chrome and firefox, if I hold CTRL and - key (to zoom out), once I get to a certain screen size, the wiggle goes away. But if I increment/zoom above a certain level, the wiggle returns. BTW, IE once again shines and has no prob regardless of screen/zoom size. Will experiment more at home later. Thanks !

Comment: overflow suggestion didn't work. w/ regard to zoom in chrome, if I shrink it to 75%, the wiggle goes away. Above 75%, it the wiggle returns ... i think it has something to do with display: none when page opens and upon slidedown, it changes to display: block and there's a wiggle. And upon slideup, it changes back to display:none and there's a wiggle. BTW, if one comment is open, then there is no wiggle when the other comment buttons are clicked.

Comment: The "wiggle" is from the page becoming longer and the scroll bar appearing and pushing the content over. Additionally, this doesn't have anything to do with razor and you should post the rendered HTML, not the  source.

Comment: @j08691 OMG, you are right !  All this time, I was pulling my hair out thinking it was a jQuery/CSS code issue. Feel free to post your response as an answer and I'll accept it. - I guess the solution is to make the page long initially so the scroll bar appears immediately. Thank you!

Comment: It's not much of an answer IMO and better suited for just a comment. You can delete the question and recover the bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're experiencing is happening because the page gets a larger height than the viewport. This means a scrollbar will appear.

Add this to your css and it will probably fix your issue

```
 html {
     overflow-y: scroll;
 }
```

Comment: this is the fix that i needed. thanks to @j08691 for pointing out the cause and thanks to Kay for the code fix. this will auto place the right side scroll even if the page is not tall enough initially. so there is no longer any wiggle as the scroll bar appears when the page gets longer since the scroll bar is already there to start.

Comment: This works, but I think showing it all the time is annoying. If it is obvious that the content scrolls you can hide it all the time. I updated my answer with the CSS.

Answer (score 2):

The scroll bar is pushing the page over a little. The two solutions are you can always show the scrollbar or you can always hide it.

Always show it:

```
body{
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Always hide it:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

If you are going to always hide it I would also add the "always show it" code. The reason is the "hide it" code with overwrite the "show it" and if your browser does not support the "show it" code it gives it a sort of fallback.

Comment: I'm looking for an IE solution. I will post it when I know it works. As far as I know there is no way to hide it on Firefox (there used to be a way that was removed).

Answer (score -2):

Remove the argument from your `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` functions:

```
 crBox.slideDown();
... 

crBox.slideUp();
```

Comment: The argument is the animation speed and removing it should not fix the issue.

Comment: That worked for the same problem i had, but for this one you should see the previous answer.